# How to optimize the rendering of a large list of items in React?

Tags: reactjs, list, performance, rendering, memoization

I have a React component that renders a large list of items (about 1000) using the map method. Each item is a complex component that has its own state and props, and can be updated by the user. The problem is that whenever I update one item, the whole list re-renders, which causes a noticeable lag and performance issue. I have tried to use React.memo and useCallback to prevent unnecessary re-rendering, but it does not seem to make much difference. How can I optimize the rendering of a large list of items in React without compromising the functionality and user experience?

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
// import React and useState hook
import React, { useState } from "react";

// define a custom component for each item
const Item = ({ item, onUpdate }) => {
  // use state to store the item data
  const [data, setData] = useState(item);

  // handle the change of the input value
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    // update the data state with the new value
    setData({ ...data, value: e.target.value });
  };

  // handle the click of the update button
  const handleClick = () => {
    // call the onUpdate prop function with the data state
    onUpdate(data);
  };

  // return the JSX element for the item
  return (
    <div className="item">
      <p>{data.name}</p>
      <input type="text" value={data.value} onChange={handleChange} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Update</button>
    </div>
  );
};

// define a custom component for the list of items
const List = ({ items }) => {
  // use state to store the items data
  const [data, setData] = useState(items);

  // handle the update of an item
  const handleUpdate = (item) => {
    // find the index of the item in the data state
    const index = data.findIndex((i) => i.id === item.id);
    // create a copy of the data state
    const newData = [...data];
    // replace the item at the index with the updated item
    newData[index] = item;
    // update the data state with the new data
    setData(newData);
  };

  // return the JSX element for the list of items
  return (
    <div className="list">
      {data.map((item) =>
        // use React.memo to memoize each item component and prevent unnecessary re-rendering
        React.memo(
          // pass the item data and handleUpdate function as props to each item component
          <Item key={item.id} item={item} onUpdate={handleUpdate} />
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

// define a mock array of items for testing
const mockItems = [
  { id: 1, name: "Item 1", value: "Value 1" },
  { id: 2, name: "Item 2", value: "Value 2" },
  { id: 3, name: "Item 3", value: "Value 3" },
];

// render the list component with the mock items
ReactDOM.render(<List items={mockItems} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> it does not seem to make much difference

Well, the difference should be significant since your app should crash due to syntax error. `React.memo` expects a *React component*, not JSX. Anyways, using `React.memo` in the way you did does not make much sense since the *memoized* component (memoized `Item`) will be re-created with every parent (`List`) re-render.

You should wrap the `Item` in the place of declaration with `React.memo` instead:

```
const Item = memo(({ item, onUpdate }) => { ... }));
```

and wrap `handleUpdate` with `useCallback`.

**Note**: Consider to avoid passing whole objects, like `item`. Try to pass only the primitives, like `item.value`.